# What do I need to do to import a word doc from a form in pdf to an api

Tags: php, forms, file

I am trying to upload a file (word doc and pdf) via a straightforward form in pdf. I can now upload the file ok... but it cannot be opened when imported presumably because it is not encrypted. Do you have any ideas what I can do to fix this?

I added the below headers

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $_FILES['file']['size'])
```

Then I am creating an array as advised by the API docs with the necessary data in to post to the API: -

```
$application['file'] = [
  'fileName' => $_FILES['file']['name'];,
  'mimeType' => $_FILES['file']['mime'],
  'fileContent' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
];
```

The file saves on the other side but cannot be opened.

Comment: Please provide some more information:

1) How your are saving this file? You know that `tmp_name` is just a temporary file and you need to copy it to some other location, right?

2) How are you serving the file besides the headers?

Comment: I am currently not saving the file. As I don't need it. I just want to ship it straight across using the API. The API requires the file contents.

Comment: So this php app serves as a proxy to other API?
In such case, show the part that is making a request to this API - setting headers using `header(...)` functions is setting a response header back to the form.

Comment: Am I the only one not clear on what "a word doc from a form in pdf" means?